# How Can I implement policyId and enable Monetization YouTube v3 with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-data-api

I found many examples with Java, Phyton and PHP, but I need to implement this with .NET C#... How Can I set PolicyId and enable monetization in my videos in Upload with YouTube v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved my problem with upload of .csv files.

[image]